# DataGrid for Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, datagrid

Can you recommend good data grid component for Zend Framework?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using http://www.datatables.net and feed them with customized JSON via Zend REST which gets all the data from models right away. Works pretty fine.

You have to generate the JSON Code by yourself, but the datatable worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dojox.grid.DataGrid`](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/dojox/HEAD/dojox.grid.DataGrid) with data from [`Zend_Dojo_Data`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dojo.data.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://code.google.com/p/kontorx/

This library is very elastic. 
You can render data as HTML table or Ext.DataGrid (JavaScript)

Live examples shows full implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ZendX_Jquery with jqGrid, which is a jQuery Plugin and very Advanced Grid component.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late answer but there is a new [library (Pike)](http://pike-project.org) which is built on top of Zend Framework and jqGrid you might like it! You can find it either on [GitHub](https://github.com/php-pike/Pike) as well.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found these projects. But they seem to be in their beginnings so I am not sure if I should invest in adopting them.

1. [zend-framework-datagrid](http://code.google.com/p/zend-framework-datagrid/)
2. [zfdatagrid](http://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid/)

[Zend_DataGrid](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_DataGrid) seems to be proposed but not yet ready.

It is also recommended to use dojo to create data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one:
http://code.google.com/p/zendscaffolding/

Simple, powerful, supports data relationship (1-N, N-N)