# Zend Framework Grid

Tags: php, zend-framework, grid

Can anyone recommend a good Zend Framework friendly table/grid API?  I'm developing an information management system and I need a component where I can display all/some of the records, and provide paging, search, sorting, and link to various actions.

I've been looking into Dojo with (dojox.grid.Grid) and it just doesn't feel right to me.  I wasn't looking to getting tied to a javascript based solution that wouldnt function properly if the browser has JS disabled.  I also don't like the infinite scroll concept, and I feel my users would be much more familiar with a paging based approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataGrid for Zend Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607102/datagrid-for-zend-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been very tempted to use this in some of my own applications, but haven't gotten the chance yet. It's jQuery based, and looks like a pretty full featured little widget:

http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 3):

This implementation looks promising:

http://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid/

It handles the pagination and filters...well, it handles a lot more than that.

Comment: After having used this for over two years, I would not recommend using it. The source code is a mess, the grid messes with the request object (allows no customization without changing source code), has a lot of bugs related to the filters and can't handle big amounts of data from a `Zend_Db_Select` source: it runs the query multiple times, gathers ALL data (also from left joins) for its pagination and callbacks convert the original data into something else so you can't use original data after running a callback on a column. The ZF2 version might be better.

Answer (score 0):

I found http://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid/ very promising as said above.

It is that good that I would like it to see it being included in ZF at some point.

It is a bit rough around the edges but it doesn't need much work to be done on it and it just works.

I spend two weeks trying to implement the dojo datagrid which I thought it'd be easier to do so since it's more ZF friendly but it just wouldn't work. Not this and some other JS datagrids I played with.

Highly recommended! I hope there will be a "clean" version soon, i.e. without the examples, just plug and play.