# Data grid for zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, datagrid

Guys

Can you advise good data grid in zend framework expect the zdgrid. I an trying to use Dojo. no result none of them is working.

As zend framework developer which one is best choise in term of functionality and implementation?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607102/datagrid-for-zend-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got less to do with ZF more to do which java-script library you know better . If you are good at jquery then I ill advice [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) . Its robust with tons of functionality which can be easily implemented both client and server side easily.